# mysqldump > unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'

Tags: mysql

I can not backup my databases by using **myslqdump**, here's the message:

```
# Error: Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA', inpossible to LOCK TABLE
```

This error-message doesn't disappear, also after we've restarted the service :-(
Our dumped file seems to be corrupted in some way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error seems to be related to the [MySQL-Bug #58406](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58406)  (status: verified).

For the moment, you can ignore that message. The process skips the table and continues as always.

Whatever, if you want to make sure that your database has not been corrupted in consequence of this error,
simply force `mysqldump` **to ignore all performance_schema-tables**:

[image] ***Parallels Plesk Panel***:

```
# mysqldump -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` --all-databases > /root/mysql.full.dump --ignore-table=performance_schema.cond_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_current --ignore-table=performance_schema.cond_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_history --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_history_long  --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_instance --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name --ignore-table=performance_schema.file_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.file_summary_by_event_name  --ignore-table=performance_schema.file_summary_by_instance  --ignore-table=performance_schema.mutex_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.performance_timers  --ignore-table=performance_schema.rwlock_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.setup_consumers --ignore-table=performance_schema.setup_instruments --ignore-table=performance_schema.setup_timers --ignore-table=performance_schema.threads
```

*Default method*:

```
# mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> --all-databases > /root/mysql.full.dump --ignore-table=performance_schema.cond_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_current --ignore-table=performance_schema.cond_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_history --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_history_long  --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_instance --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name --ignore-table=performance_schema.events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name --ignore-table=performance_schema.file_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.file_summary_by_event_name  --ignore-table=performance_schema.file_summary_by_instance  --ignore-table=performance_schema.mutex_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.performance_timers  --ignore-table=performance_schema.rwlock_instances --ignore-table=performance_schema.setup_consumers --ignore-table=performance_schema.setup_instruments --ignore-table=performance_schema.setup_timers --ignore-table=performance_schema.threads
```